# Postgres Greatest Query not returning correct timestamp

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I think I might be writing this query incorrectly. Essentially, I want to find the object with the latest timestamp across four possible values (in this example, user_id is 1).

```
SELECT *, GREATEST(books.updated_at, books.deleted_at, posts.updated_at, posts.deleted_at)
FROM books, posts WHERE books.user_id = 1
OR posts.user_id = 1
```

This will always return a time for `updated_at`, but even if the `deleted_at` time for one of the objects is the latest, it will not return a `deleted_at` time. I know, because running a query for `deleted_at IS NOT NULL` returned a later timestamp.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The JOIN condition looks weird. `books.user_id = #{self.id}
OR posts.user_id = #{self.id}`? Perhaps you wanted AND there instead of OR?

Comment: Keep in mind that GREATEST and LEAST ignore NULL values. Have a look at [Postgresql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) about it.

Comment: Perhaps it's my lack of Postgres knowledge but ... I don't see a join clause between the two tables ... do you really want a cartesian product?

Comment: @McNets Thank you, I appreciate that. It's no problem if they ignore all NULL values, I have that built into my code. I appreciate the heads up.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Thank you, I appreciate it. I'm not sure that's where the issue is coming from, but let me take a look and get back to you if it is.

Comment: @markp Yeah, I'm looking for a cartesian product. Essentially, I have a lot of different tables, and I need to get a single greatest timestamp out of multiple columns across them. As I'm looking for a timestamp and not a specific object, unless a join would speed that up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got it figured out and I'm leaving the answer for posterity.

Essentially, remove the `*` from the query and add a LIMIT 1 and it all appears to work. In addition, as @ypercubetm stated, you can use AND in place of OR, but it depends on your usecase.

```
SELECT GREATEST(books.updated_at, books.deleted_at, posts.updated_at, posts.deleted_at) AS greatest_time
FROM books, posts WHERE books.user_id = 1
OR posts.user_id = 1 ORDER BY greatest_time DESC LIMIT 1;
```

returns a single, latest time.